# Responsive CSS/jQuery menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I'm making a website that works also for mobile, responsive.
I can make the most of my website into responsive, so it's al working nice on mobile. But there is only one problem, the menu. Logo on the left, the links to the other pages on the right. The height of the menu and the logo schould not changing only the links to like a drop down menu or just a simple iOS based drop down menu. Is there any link for a simple menu for mobile - formats?

Comment: Could you at least show us what you have tried or some code?

Comment: We are here to help not to do Show your try

Answer (score 0):

Good examples about responsive navigation patterns here: http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html#navigation

Comment: Thank you for this great website! I hope I can get a right menu.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap is typically a good option for implementing responsive design. Take a look at the library [here](http://getbootstrap.com/). You can customize it to suit your needs prior to download.